# How to attach .mdf file to SQL Server 2005 without an .ldf file?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to attach a database to SQL Server 2005 but I have only its `.mdf` file

How can I attach it?

Comment: Depends on whether it was cleanly shut down or not whether or not you can do so without problems.

Comment: Have you tried something before asking? Making a quick search using almost same words as your first post is http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/04/26/sql-server-attach-mdf-file-without-ldf-file-in-database/

Answer (score 8):

E.g like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 ON (FILENAME = '{drive}:\{file path}\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf') FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG;
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply,When you attach database, it will display `Attach Database` dialog box in which  click the logfile location  and click the remove button. When you click OK, a logfile for you database will be created....

[image]

Comment: but I dont have a log file to remove..

Answer (score 2):

When you attach the mdf via the UI, select the ldf file in the list of files and remove it. A new one will be created.